# Aligning element to Stack

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React/MUI, so a little help would be great.

I have a Stack of `TextFields`, they are resizing with the screen width very nicely.

```
<Stack
        direction="row"
        sx={{
          margin: "16px"
        }}
      >
        <Stack sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <Box sx={{ flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
            <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
          </Box>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
```

I am trying to put an action button that is:

- always aligned to the right of the screen
- always stays on the same row with at least one `TextField` (never on its own row)
- does not take all vertical space (`TextFields` can be on top and to the left of it)

The closest I got is to wrap it in `flex-inline`, `block-inline` `Box`, but I cannot always satisfy all the requirements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone put a correct answer but then deleted it for whatever reason, therefore I am reposting it:

```
<Stack
  sx={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    minWidth: "360px",
  }}
  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
   <Box
            sx={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              flexShrink: 0,
            }}
          />
    </Box>

</Stack>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Stack` has a default `flexDirection` of `column`. You can change it to `row`.

To align to the right you can use `justifyContent: "end"`.

For the minimal 2 at a row you can add a `minWidth: "360px"` which is twice the TextField width.

```js
<Stack
  sx={{
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "end",
    minWidth: "360px",
  }}
>
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
  <TextField sx={{ width: "180px" }} />
</Stack>
```

Comment: What I was asking is to how to add a button to this

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding @GRZa where would you like the button to be placed?